# Effect of Angular Acceleration on Fluid Pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Consider a fluid kept in a cylindrical container rotating with some angular acceleration $\alpha$ about its central axis. Now I know $$\nabla P + \rho \vec{a} = \rho \vec{g}$$
Now, due to the angular acceleration of the vessel, a tangential acceleration exists, which implies that pressure must vary with the angular position from the axis. However, that seems to violate my idea of symmetry and more importantly, there is no definitive zero gauge pressure point. So, how does the pressure vary due to such a motion?

Comment: Why do you feel that the pressure varies with angular position?

Comment: Angular acceleration will probably change with distance from the center. Did you mean _pressure must vary with the **radial distance** from the axis?_ That does not violate symmetry.